# How to handle multiple different type of response for an single rest call using retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, simple-framework

How to handle multiple different type of response for an single rest call using retrofit like for error i have different response and for success i have different response both are no where related , can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
  @Override
public void failure(RetrofitError error)
{
    RestError restError = (RestError) error.getBodyAs(RestError.class);
}
```